# Retrieving a value from a node child process

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var fp = 'ffprobe ' + fileName + ' -show_streams | grep '
var width = exec(fp+'width', function(err, stdout, stderr){
    return stdout;
});
alert(stdout + 'random example');
```

how do I get the stdout 'out' of the process so that I can use it later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Node's [`exec`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.9/api/child_processes.html#child_process.exec) function is asynchronous. This means that there is no guarantee that code below the `exec` call will wait until the child process finishes to run. To execute code once the process quits, then, you must provide a callback which deals with the results. Your code can branch off from there:

```
var fp = 'ffprobe ' + fileName + ' -show_streams | grep ';
var width = exec(fp+'width', function(err, stdout, stderr){
    console.log(stdout);

    // ... process stdout a bit ...

    afterFFProbe(stdout);
});

function afterFFProbe(output) {
    // your program continues here
}
```

Comment: `stdout` appears blank for me :( i had to use `stderr`

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers above worked for me. This did though.

```
var probeCommand = 'rtsp://xx.xx.xx.xx/axis-media/media.3gp'
exec('ffprobe '+probeCommand+' | echo ',function(err,stdout,stderr){
    console.log(stdout+stderr)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

If I'm understanding you correctly:

```
var fp = 'ffprobe ' + fileName + ' -show_streams | grep ',
    value,
    width = exec(fp+'width', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        value = stdout;
        return stdout;
    });
alert(value + 'random example');
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this might work:

```
var output = "";
var fp = 'ffprobe ' + fileName + ' -show_streams | grep '
var width = exec(fp+'width', function(err, stdout, stderr){
this.output = stdout;
});
alert(output + 'random example');
```